# Merge received data from API with data from database

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a method in my Laravel application:

```
private function mergeSurveysWithCases($surveys){

        foreach($surveys as $survey ){
             $surveyId  = $survey->survey->id;
        $caseSurvey = $this->SurveysRepository->findOneBy(['survey' => $surveyId]);
        $caseId = $caseSurvey->getCase()->getId();
        $firstContant = $this->caseRepository->getFirstContactByCase($caseId);
        $survey->caseData = ["caseId" => $caseId,
                             "firstContact" => $firstContant
        ];
        }
        return $surveys;
    }
```

As we can see argument of this method is $surveys. This is a json response with array of surveys from API. Every survey has form like below:

```
{
    "hash": "8537f99bb4166da9f74f02ebb70907cf",
    "sending_date": "2017-08-23T08:32:37+02:00",
    "expiration_date": "2018-02-23T08:32:37+01:00",
    "created_at": "2017-08-23T08:32:37+02:00",
    "trans_id": "10-550\r\n",
    "id": 18,
    "status": {
        "name": "new",
        "id": 1
    },
    "base_survey": {
        "name": "Base Survey Test 1",
        "created_at": "2017-07-25T10:08:18+02:00",
        "creator_trans_id": "10-615",
        "date_start": "2017-07-25T00:00:00+02:00",
        "expiration_int": 6,
        "expiration_string": "months",
        "survey_prefix": "PSI",
        "welcome_message": "test1",
        "expiration_message": "test2",
        "id": 1,
        "template": {
            "path": "/template_ssi_1/",
            "name": "SSI",
            "id": 1
        }
    }
}
```

In application I have a relational table which connect objects wchich are called **cases** with object **surveys**. I show below Entities from this table:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Entities\Cic;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cic_case_survey")
 */
class CicCaseSurvey
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CicCase", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="case_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    protected $case;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="survey_id", type = "integer")
     *
     */
    protected $survey;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $updated_at;

    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt() {
        $this->created_at = Carbon::now();
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt() {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt() {
        $this->updated_at = Carbon::now();
    }

    public function getSurvey()
    {
        return $this->survey;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $survey
     */
    public function setSurvey($survey)
    {
        $this->survey = $survey;
    }

    public function getCase()
    {
        return $this->case;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $case
     */
    public function setCase($case)
    {
        $this->case = $case;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

}
```

After response from API I'm trying to connect based on table cic_case_survey

data from cases with data in surveys obejcts. As we can see from method **mergeSurveysWithCases**  I've done  merging in loop where I use **findOneBy** method for every connection case data(case Id and firstContact) with survey data. In my opinion this solution is not optimal. I think it will work very bad for a lot of data. Does anyone perhaps know a better solution of merging this objects? I would be very grateful for help
Best regards ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, in your case task should be decribed as "deserialize entity from Json array". Than, maybe you should make it with the help of some third-party serializer library that will do most of the work for you. I personally use JMSSerializer: it depends on doctrine annotations - so you will only need to add annotations metadata on your entities and provide deserialized entity type to serializer to get this work. You can get more details here: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer